# Sql Server removing end 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

When I insert a price into my database, using datatype decimal, the following happens;

20.50 becomes 20.5, 
110.00 becomes 110
, and so on, which looks pretty untidy on my application.

Whilst I am sure this is pretty easy to change, I can't find the setting, or find a solution to the issue online.

Could anyone tell me how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: The *values* `20.5` and `20.50` are the same, they only differ in *formatting*, that is how they're displayed vs. how they're stored. In your application, you must format your values using your language's built in formatting functions.

Comment: That's something you'd fix in the application, not the database.

Comment: try `format()` like this: `select FORMAT(cast(20.5 as decimal(6,3)),'#,0.00')` in sql-server 2012 and up